# Gallery Shortcode Showing IDs

Tags: gallery

I'm trying to include a gallery in my custom post type.  The image gallery works in the editor, but when I view the post I get this.

[gallery link="file" ids="590,589,588,587,586,585,578,580,581,582,583,584"]

My content looks like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = get_the_content();
    /** ... **/
?>
    <p><?php echo $content ; ?></p>
```

[image]

Comment: Does your template use `the_content()` to output post content?

Comment: Does your theme have any filters on `the_content`? Have you tried disabling all plugins and switching to the default theme to narrow down your issue?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks for the reply, managed to figure it out with Milo's help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove:

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

and replace:

```
<p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
```

with:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

See this note on the Codex page for [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content):

> An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content() does not pass the content through the 'the_content' filters. This means that get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things.